# How to remap a keyboard key which outputs multiple key codes?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping, keymap

So I got this keyboard with this extremely atrocious design which was overlooked while buying:

[image]

> *Why would you put a Euro key there?!!! Also, it doesn't even output the Euro sign on Linux.*

So basically I want to remap that Euro key to the Left Shift key. I tried to follow the standard ways listed elsewhere, but they are all about (or explain with) one key outputting one single key code, which is not the case here.

Here are some outputs of `showkey` (for the key in question). It also prints `0128` first on the terminal after pressing, which I omitted below.

```
$ sudo showkey -k

keycode  56 press
keycode  82 press
keycode  82 release
keycode  79 press
keycode  79 release
keycode  80 press
keycode  80 release
keycode  72 press
keycode  72 release
keycode  56 release
```

```
$ sudo showkey -s

0x38 0x52 0xd2 0x4f 0xcf 0x50 0xd0 0x48 0xc8 0xb8
```

```
$ sudo showkey -a

0    48 0060 0x30
1    49 0061 0x31
2    50 0062 0x32
8    56 0070 0x38
```

How should I remap the key in question to `left shift`?

---

Edit: Found out it is just `Alt + 0128` (where numbers are from numpad), which outputs Euro sign Windows.